# ActiveMQ uses 100% CPU

Tags: memory-leaks, activemq-classic, message-queue, cpu-usage

I use AMQ v 5.9.0 with **non-persistent message** and below settings:

```
    <policyEntry queue="foo.bar.>" memoryLimit="500mb" producerFlowControl="false">
            <pendingQueuePolicy>
                <fileQueueCursor />
            </pendingQueuePolicy>
          </policyEntry>
```

Heap Size below

```
-Xmx and Xmx  set up 1GB/1GB.
```

My problem is when I send (for example 300 000 messages) into my queue and AMQ initialise KahaDB **"Temp percent used" > 0** I leave it for a night and in the next day I send another messages (10 000 for example). I noticed that my CPU increase to 100%, memory about 80-90% and AMQ console is freezing. This situation is all the time, when I wait a night.  I was looking for some information why is this happening, but I didn't find anything.

Maybe anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: This post is also on this site http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMQ-uses-100-CPU-td4699129.html;cid=1436794562675-770

Answer (score 0):

If you use a version of openJDK lower than 9 you should try to upgrade your openJDK version.

The problem explaination [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2015/05/08/productionalizing-active-mq)

The openJDK issue [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054446)